# Force all && to be executed?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, logic, variadic-templates

Consider the following variadic function

```
template <typename Type, typename... Types>
bool f(Type& arg, Types&... args)
{
    return f(arg) && f(args...);
}

template <typename Type>
bool f(Type& arg)
{
    // Do something
}
```

If one level of recursion is `false`, then I suspect that the following will not be executed. Is there a trick to force the recursion on all arguments even if one of them returns `false` ?

Comment: How about replacing `&&` with `&`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This shouldn't be too hard:

```
template <typename Type, typename... Types>
bool f(Type& arg, Types&... args)
{
    bool b1 = f(arg);
    bool b2 = f(args...);
    return b1 && b2;
}
```

Comment: I think just get rid of the second calls to `f`.

Comment: Why do you need `f(arg)`? Shouldn't that just be `bool b1 = arg`?

Answer (score 10):

As the debate has evolved in a comparison of the AndyProwl and Alon solution, I've benchmarked the both solution, and the result ... depends of the number of arguments.

Compiling with:

```
g++-4.7 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -O3 main.cpp -o main -D_FIRST
```

benchmarks the AndyProwl solution and compiling with :

```
g++-4.7 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -O3 main.cpp -o main -D_SECOND
```

benchmarks the Alon solution.

Here is the program of the benchmark for 10 arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

// Function 1 : with &&
template <typename Type>
inline bool f1(const Type& arg)
{
   return arg;
}
template <typename Type, typename... Types>
inline bool f1(const Type& arg, const Types&... args)
{
    bool arg1 = f1(arg);
    bool arg2 = f1(args...);
    return arg1 && arg2;
}

// Function 2 : with &
template <typename Type>
inline bool f2(const Type& arg)
{
   return arg;
}
template <typename Type, typename... Types>
inline bool f2(const Type& arg, const Types&... args)
{
    return f2(arg) & f2(args...);
}

// Benchmark
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Variables
    static const unsigned long long int primes[10] = {11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43};
    static const unsigned long long int nbenchs = 50;
    static const unsigned long long int ntests = 10000000;
    unsigned long long int sum = 0;
    double result = 0;
    double mean = 0;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Loop of benchmarks
    for (unsigned long long int ibench = 0; ibench < nbenchs; ++ibench) {

        // Initialization
        t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        sum = 0;

        // Loop of tests
        for (unsigned long long int itest = 1; itest <= ntests; ++itest) {
#ifdef _FIRST
            sum += f1((itest+sum)%primes[0], (itest+sum)%primes[1], (itest+sum)%primes[2], (itest+sum)%primes[3], (itest+sum)%primes[4], (itest+sum)%primes[5], (itest+sum)%primes[6], (itest+sum)%primes[7], (itest+sum)%primes[8], (itest+sum)%primes[9]);
#endif
#ifdef _SECOND
            sum += f2((itest+sum)%primes[0], (itest+sum)%primes[1], (itest+sum)%primes[2], (itest+sum)%primes[3], (itest+sum)%primes[4], (itest+sum)%primes[5], (itest+sum)%primes[6], (itest+sum)%primes[7], (itest+sum)%primes[8], (itest+sum)%primes[9]);
#endif
        }

        // Finalization
        result = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()-t0).count();
        mean += result;
        std::cout<<"time = "<<result<<" (sum = "<<sum<<")"<<std::endl;
    }

    // End
    std::cout<<"mean time = "<<mean/nbenchs<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With 50 benchmarks for each solution with a given number of arguments, the dispersion is very small, and the mean time over these benchmarks is a reliable indicator.

My first benchmark has been with the "right" number of arguments where the Alon solution is faster than the AndyProwl solution.

The final results are here :

[image: Benchmark]

So the AndyProwl solution is generally faster than the Alon one. So, now I can validate your answer. But I think that the difference is so small that it's architecture/compiler dependent.

So:

- AndyProwl+1 for your generally faster solution
- Alon+1 for your constexpr-ready solution

Comment: As I have posted the code, you can run it several times and compute the dispersion.

Comment: Both solutions are interchangeable, in that a compiler could execute one instead of the other by the "as-if" principle. There are no side-effects and the result is the same. So, at best, your benchmark detects a potential optimization miss. -1

Comment: In fact, both approaches result in exactly the same code, e.g. for the two-argument case. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/f4bWGG).

Answer (score 4):

You can execute them separately and return a bool expression:

```
bool b0 = f(arg);
bool b1 = f(args);
return b0 && b1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Without recursion:

```
template <typename... Types>
bool f(Types&&... args)
{
  bool r=true;
  (void)std::initializer_list<bool>{(r = f(args)&&r)...};
  return r;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a much nicer trick,
instead of using && between all the functions, just use one &

`static_cast<bool>(f(arg)) & static_cast<bool>(f2(args))`
... will run all operations regardless of the result :)

Comment: Unless they return `int` instead of `bool` and the values are `1` and `2` and you suddenly get `false` instead of `true`. Sorry, -1.

Comment: This can be fixed with `static_cast<bool>`. I like this approach since it's more compact than the ones with helper variables.

Comment: I like it too, casting int to boolean is easy, and it's nice and compact:), too bad tricks yield such negative votes :D, @Ipc editted due to comment

Comment: @Alon: In *most* cases? Which only means it would be a much more dangerous bug. But OK, you "fixed" it, so I'm taking the -1 back. But it's not "nice" anymore (IMHO).

Comment: @Alon Without doing `static_cast<bool>` on both sides, it's very easy to get a fake false. Note that `(2 && 4) == true`, but `(2 & 4) == false`.

Comment: Tested here for my example : http://liveworkspace.org/code/3brT09$6 , works well.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a "much nicer trick". It just makes the code harder to read, debug, and maintain. @Vincent: Why wouldn't you just use temporary variables? There's no performance penalty, if that's what you're concerned with, and it makes your intent clear. This one doesn't. People who are used to read C++ actually *expect* to see the short-circuiting when reading a piece of code like this one, because this is the usual behavior and because `&` is **not** usual for the logical conjunction. You don't have to accept my answer, just please don't learn from this.

Comment: @AndyProwl: I agree that in 90% of situations your answer is a lot easier to read/debug/maintain. For this specific situation I asked for a "trick" to do this (if possible without temporary variables) because in my code, this inlined very low level function will be called hundreds of billion times on supercomputers.

Comment: @Andy: Maybe not a "much nicer", but it's certainly a _trick_ that's not always common knowledge.. I thought I'll put my input... I do agree it  makes the code harder to read(or rather, understand)..

Comment: @Vincent: Doing it this way won't bring you one femtosecond of performance gain, any compiler will just optimize the temporary variables away. And if the compiler is really dumb, then I see it likelier that it will introduce a performance penalty for *this* version, because of the conversions to `bool` and the bitwise &.

Comment: @AndyProwl: I will have to check the assembly, but I've just done 4 series of 50 benchmarks on your solution and this one (without the static_cast, as f returns a boolean), and this one is 7.5% faster than yours (g++ 4.7.2 with -O3).

Comment: @Vincent: I would be curious to see those benchmarks, because it's hard to believe that there isn't something wrong with them...

Comment: @AndyProwl: Ok I am cleaning the code and I will post it on LWS.